# Why am I unable to run "pod update"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

Whenever I try to run `pod update` in my project folder, I get the following error:

````
### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 0.29.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
    RubyGems : 2.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B3116)
       Xcode : 5.0.2 (5A3005)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 56f3f79d03ef66e11abefc7c634b3bcdd6426577
```

### Podfile

```ruby
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'RedditKit', '~> 1.0'
pod 'UIView+AutoLayout'
pod 'GPUImage'
```

### Error

```
TypeError - Plist contains a hash value object type unsupported by Xcodeproj.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:172:in `read_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:172:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:93:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:489:in `block in compute_target_platforms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:486:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:486:in `compute_target_platforms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:55:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:171:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:94:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:52:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:93:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:86:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:38:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:82:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:213:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```
````

How exactly would I go about remedying this? To my knowledge I haven't touched anything Cocoapods related except changing my podfile to include another library.

I tried this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/119 and it did not work. I duplicated it, removed the original then renamed the duplicate and it still failed.

In the first line it gives it mentions a file and here's the line it references:

```
172       plist = Xcodeproj.read_plist(pbxproj_path.to_s)
```

Comment: don't know if you have tried this https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1724 it looks exactly like your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try going to Build Settings and changing `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO`. I had a similar problem and this worked for me.

If your project requires `Build Active Architecture Only` to be set to `YES`, it also works if you change the value to `NO`, clean and build, then set it back to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i hope to fixed it by moving your ProjectName/ProjectName-Info.plist file to ProjectName/ProjectName-Info.plist.bac , then running pod install.

After restored the ProjectName-Info.plist. Everything seems to work as expected.